# Why Copying an instance of object in a loop takes a huge memory in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, ram, instance-variables

I have written a program which works iteratively to find some solution. I initially used vectors to have instances of an object. It worked fine but I preferred to have and instance of the class as the primary object and a temp object which is made in a while loop through some kind of instance copying. It works fine but slower. it also occupies almost two times more RAM memory space. (e.g. 980 Mb first and after that change it take about 1.6 Gb) why? I really have no Idea. I Took the line of "copying" (which is not technically copy constructor but works the same way) out of loop and it works as expected with expected RAM usage, so the problem arises when the "copying line" is inside the loop. Any Idea why this happens?

a simplified preview of code:

```
void SPSA::beginIteration(Model ins, Inventory inv_Data, vector <Result> &res)
{
bool icontinue=true;

while(icontinue)
{
    Model ins_temp(&ins, &inv_Data);
    if(model_counter>0)
        ins_temp.setDecesionVariableIntoModel(decisionVariable);
//something useful here
    model_counter++;
}
```

}

The code above occupies a lot of RAM space.
but code below is ok:

```
void SPSA::beginIteration(Model ins, Inventory inv_Data, vector <Result> &res)
{
bool icontinue=true;
Model ins_temp(&ins, &inv_Data);
while(icontinue)
{
    if(model_counter>0)
        ins_temp.setDecesionVariableIntoModel(decisionVariable);
//something useful here
    model_counter++;
}
}
```

By the way, I'm compiling using using mingw++.
Thanks

Comment: So what does your InsuranceModel class look like ? Is it allocating a lot of memory that you forgot to release again ?

Comment: @nos I used memory allocation in that copy constructor but through some vector stl, assuming they have their own de-constructor (and truely they have) that should be not a problem. Let think I'm wrong about vectors de-constructor, the allocation inside copy constructor is not that much of memory, still (examined before). If It was so, the memory allocation should increase through the runtime which does not happen.

Comment: There is probably a memory leak in the class Model. Make sure that its destructor deletes all memory owned by the instance.

Comment: I have not declared any pointer inside class model. Only vectors which have their own de-constructors. The only pointer I used here is pointer as arguement in copy constructor. @user763305

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is copying the Model N times (once for each loop body execution, depending on when `icontinue` is set) rather than once.

First, try to reduce the problem:

```
while(1) Model ins_temp(&ins, &inv_Data);
```

If that eats memory as well (significantly), yet, it's a problem with `Model`. 
(Above loop may eat a little memory due to fragmentation - depending on how `Model` is implemented.)

**Most likely cause** (without additional information) is a memory leak in `Model`.

Other possibilities include: `Model` uses a lazy memory release (such as / similar to a garbage collector), `Model` uses shared pointers and creating more than one instance causes circular references, or you are running into a very ugly, very bad memory fragmentation problem (extremely unlikely).

**How to proceed**

The "pro" solution would be using a memory profiler ([options for mingw](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2009/03/valgrind-for-mingw/)). 
Alternatively, study your code of `Model` for leaks, or reduce the implementation of `Model` until you find the minimal change that makes the leak go away.

Comment: I used STL classes so I would not worry for memory leak. Is that true?
but I'm more concerned with memory fragmentation. Actually I didn't know what it is and I read somewhere that STL class can cause such thing. In fact some of the instances rationally use a lot of memory and I have a mixture of long and short life object instances. So I think memory fragmentation is the main culprit.

Comment: Litmus test: does your implementation contain `new` or `malloc`? Do  you have pointers (a std::vector of pointers can leak as well)?  ---- Do **not** worry about memory fragmentation at this point.  I listed it for completeness, mostly.

Comment: I have made another compile without -o2 option and this this time it's okay. It's still weird because I have done it before, but hadn't worked. @peterchen

Answer (score 0):

Don't be scared immediately if your code appears to use a lof of memory. It doesn't necessarily mean there's a memory leak. C++ may not always return memory to the OS, but keep it on hand for future allocations. It only counts as a memory leak if C++ loses track of the allocation status and cannot use that memory for future allocations anymore.

The fact that the memory doubles regardless of the iteration count suggests that the memory is recycled not on the very first opportunity, but on every second allocation. Presumably you end up with two big allocations which are used alternatingly.

It's even possible that if the second allocation had failed, the first block *would* have been recycled, so you use 1.6 GB of memory because it's there.